# What does 'our own intrinsic moral value' mean?

Tags: ethics

> [[60% down the page]](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/charity/duty_1.shtml): [Heading:] Is this [a duty to give] too demanding?
>
> Singer's argument is clear, and when you consider the drowning child example, pretty seductive.
>
> But it does impose very high obligations on those of us who live in comparatively rich countries, and it may be just too demanding.
>
> ●... **It fails to recognise our own intrinsic moral value as persons.**

I know no philosophy, so would someone please explain the meaning of the bolded, basically and simply (without cant or abstract parlance)?  How does 'donating' imply the above? Wouldn't bona fide donation confirm and improve our morality?

Comment: Well, donations are tax deductible. There's always that.

Comment: ps ... If you Google "bona fide donation" this is what you get. http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/42/433.54 God doesn't care if your donation is "bona fide" or not, God just wants you to take care of your fellow humans.

Comment: There's nothing very deep about that particular bullet, and as a counterargument to Singer, it overlaps with the bullet which precedes it and the one which follows it. In short: if I'm obliged to support another human being simply because he's a human being (i.e. he has *intrinsic moral value*), then, because I, too, am a human being (I have my own *intrinsic moral value*), the same argument applies to me: I should support myself. I can give starving Sam $5 or give myself $5 and the same ends have been met: a human being with *intrinsic moral value* has been given $5.

Comment: Value here has exactly the same meaning as in your other question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/does-all-the-value-that-we-associate-with-persons-always-hold-true

Answer (score 3):

Part of what's confusing here is that no connection is offered between this objection and the terms of Singer's argument. Indeed, there may not be a reasonable connection between them. I will therefore answer your question and then make the connection best I can:

Something has “intrinsic value” if it has value *in itself*, independently of its relationship to anything else. The alternative to this is being valuable because of a relationship to other things. This latter kind of value, “extrinsic value,” is the kind of value cars have. Their value lies in their relationship to human beings and human beings' goals. People likes their cars because they allow those people to drive places. In the absence of any need or desire to drive anyplace, or any other reason for appreciating cars, or in the absence of people, cars would probably have no value at all. Something with intrinsic value, on the other hand, cannot lose its value this way. It it always valuable, and should be valued, regardless of how the world is, or who has what interests and desires.

It is a matter of debate whether anything at all has intrinsic value. Some people claim that human lives have intrinsic value. Others claim that happiness has intrinsic value. If these or other things have intrinsic value, it would be *unreasonable* or *incorrect* not to value them.

So, the accusation here is that Singer's argument does not treat people as beings whom it would be unreasonable not to value. But the outline you linked to does not say why. One possible reason would be to say that if we have a moral obligation to give things to others in extraordinary need, to the extent that we can, that obligation undercuts our freedom to do anything we want with what we have. If you believe that, you must believe that a thing with intrinsic value ought to be free of any moral obligations, and that to admit that we have moral obligations to others is to undermine our status as intrinsically valuable beings.

I'm afraid that I cannot think of, nor have ever heard, any reasonable or semi-reasonable rationale for why an intrinsically valuable thing ought not, by virtue of being intrinsically valuable, have any moral obligations to others. I think it's just sloppily expressed on that page.